# Laravel query scope combination

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 4.2 Query Scopes but encountered a problem.

My Model:

```
class SomeModel extends Eloquent {
    public function scopeS1($query) {
        return $query->where('field1', '=', 'S1');
    }
    public function scopeS2($query) {
        return $query->where('field2', '=', 'S2');
    }
}
```

Now when I do `SomeModel::s1()->s2()->get();` it returns all results and doesn't filter by `S1` AND `S2`. Note also that I have no problem when I do

```
SomeModel::where('field1', '=', 'S1')->where('field2', '=', 'S2')->get()
```

So why is query scoping and doing anything here??

Comment: What does `SomeModel::s1()->s2()->toSql()` return?

Comment: It happens that the returned result is different depending on the order of s1() and s2() usage. My scope functions are a bit more complex than what I have in question, so won't bother entering the `toSql()` here but what should be noted is that I don't see any paranthese around operators in the SQL output, which I think explains the issue. So how can I do, for example `(field1 = 'S1' OR field1 = 'any') AND field2 = 'S2'` instead of `field1 = 'S1' OR field1 = 'any' AND field2 = 'S2'` using scopes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your real scopes contain OR conditions you should use a nested where to make sure they get interpreted correctly. Laravel will wrap parentheses around.

```
public function scopeS1($query) {
    return $query->where(function($q){
        $q->where('field1', '=', 'S1')
          ->orWhere('foo', '=', 'bar');
    });
}

// and the same for scopeS2...
```

Comment: lovely gobely! I never used nested `where`s in Laravel before. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much. I had an issue that queries to the current model would fail because it would fetch ALL possible relationships instead of the relationships belonging to relations. doing a `$that = $this;$query->where(function($query) use ($that){});` I was able to use the objects properly. You saved me from a 6 hour horror in which I could not figure out why it would fail.